# How to convert PDF to html and dynamic values to the html file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

In my project there is a option to upload a pdf file. In that pdf file there are some input boxes for name and ID. These values should be dynamically added to the pdf,and make it available for download.
I tried to convert pdf to html first so that I can easily add the dynamic values,but it is not coverting properly. I am able to convert this into plain text only.
Guys please help me out how  to convert html to pdf either using Javascript or c# and append those dynamic values

Comment: The question you have linked ,it is coverting html to pdf, i want the viceversa

Comment: I think it will be easier if you create an HTML form. And then, input some data that you want. Finally, export HTML form to the pdf file.